# Embedding Javascript (file): what means "filename.js?v=2.0.4"?

Tags: javascript

what purpose/advantage has the following syntax referencing a javascript file with the parameter "v(version)"?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/file.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
```

Thanks!
mtemp

Sorry: [Why pass parameters to CSS and JavaScript link files like src="../cnt.js?ver=4.0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131518/why-pass-parameters-to-css-and-javascript-link-files-like-src-cnt-jsver-4-0)