# How to compile css file

Tags: css

I've seen this on a site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blablas.com/built/assets-styles.css?v=12355" />
```

which need to be underlined `assets-styles.css?v=12355"`

How to compile css file as above?

is it possible with less or sass?

[update]

And How about this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://blablas.com/built/assets-201501-35b4b2bf0e75bb40f98d111b2d97951d.css">
```

Comment: You should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131518/why-pass-parameters-to-css-and-javascript-link-files-like-src-cnt-jsver-4-0

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing todo with Compiling CSS! You use it for Cache Control. Everytime the CSS File gets changed they just need to change the numer and the new version gets requested.

In the 1st Link you posted ist a GET Variable therefore ist more likely to be vor some inernal Processing

Comment: oke, how about this?
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blablas.com/built/assets-201501-35b4b2bf0e75bb40f98d111b2d97951d.css" >

Comment: There is no way to compile CSS

Comment: how i can generate numeric like =  assets-201501-35b4b2bf0e75bb40f98d111b2d97951d.css

Comment: Why doyou need to do so?

Comment: before, why people use that numeric for css link? sorry i'm newbie.

Comment: I already stated that:  Ist a Version number. You use it for Cache Control. Everytime the CSS File gets changed they just need to change the numer and the new version gets requested.

Comment: if i include css file (like bootstrap) it will display so.

Answer (score 0):

CSS files are not to be compiled.
The reason the URI parameter is there could be it is not really a CSS file that's called, but a PHP engine (with mod_rewrite) that returns a CSS file based on the given parameter.

Another reason to use parameters is to force web browser to fetch the stylesheet again when necessary.