# What do these numbers in path meen?

Tags: css

I have in project link to the `.css` file like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?dt=20140207115301">
```

But i don't know what does `dt=20140207115301` mean ?

Any ideas what is it?`

Comment: Have a look here, should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131518/why-pass-parameters-to-css-and-javascript-link-files-like-src-cnt-jsver-4-0

Comment: Cache invalidation, aka "cachebusting".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Date Time stamp (dt) to me. Basically a unique token to perform cache busting. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/) has a good article on CacheBusting if you want alternate implementations, but esentially all its doing is ensuring that the browser will re-request the file on each deployment as the timestamp will change

Comment: okay, if i changed file style.css, will it be shown in browser?

Comment: Yes, assuming the timestamp changes (what is generating this for you?) or you've disabled client side caching...

Comment: i do not now how it works. I faced with it first. I do changes in file but this changes do not work

Comment: What are you using to produce these timestamps/suffixes? You'll need something server side (either at a web server level (e.g. IIS) or application level (e.g. asp.net MVC) to generate these for you