# Sintax of href=" css?STRING" or href="..js?STRING"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm tryng to understand how-to manage sites HTML to give useful information and nice to see. To make that I'm looking for everiting done yet.
Understanding how other sites are made seems very hard. I have seen syntaxes unexplained in standard system. 
In particular referring to the site https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/curecoin/
There is codes like:

```
<link href="/static/compressed/base.min.css?71b30c07"
```

or

```
<script src="/static/compressed/detail.min.js?54fdecbe"></script>
```

Seems to be a query o a param passage, or someting else that I don't know.

Can someone help me to understand this issue?

NB: there isn't any  param like version after the question mark

Thanks
Luigi

Comment: What is the issue? Yes, they are query strings.

Comment: This is usually a workaround to force the browser to re-load the resource instead of using the cached version. Nothing you need to worry about building a basic site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why pass parameters to CSS and JavaScript link files like src="../cnt.js?ver=4.0"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131518/why-pass-parameters-to-css-and-javascript-link-files-like-src-cnt-jsver-4-0)